# Get telegram channel username by id

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have exported json channel list from Telegram. How can I convert this ids to channel names **@channel1, @channel2**?

```
    {
    "name": "Кухня Яндекс.Дзена",
    "type": "public_channel",
    "id": 9819909683,
    "messages": [
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "Яндекс.Дзен",
    "type": "public_channel",
    "id": 9736917893,
    "messages": [
    ]
   },
```

Comment: are you using telegram-cli? or how you obtained the json?

Comment: I'm using Win Telegram Desktop client, exported JSON manually :)